# Embedding yammer in small sections

Tags: sharepoint, embed, customization, yammer

I'm using Yammer Embed to show a network feed on a SharePoint Intranet's homepage. Webpart's width is 460px.

PROBLEM:

- A terrible **horizontal scroll** is rendered within the iframe when feed contains large images. Yammer embedded don't re-size images enough to fit in a small area like this one.

AT A GLANCE:

1) Skinny Mode (less than 400px) seems to remove some elements like profile picture but other feed pictures remain there.

2) Customizing everything from scratch using REST API is not an option for now, $ and time.

Has anyone come across this issue with Yammer Embed? Any ideas or options I'm missing here? Some attribute in the config section to ignore images or force a max width will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no workaround for this as Embed in Skinny mode removes too many components, and Yammer does not promote creating everything from scratch using the APIs.

I think we can all agree this is not expected behavior though. I've filed an internal bug for this. Thanks for reporting.

---

Update (8/19/2014):

A fix for the horizontal scrollbar will ship tonight.